# Goldbach's conjecture and Euler's Totient function

Tags: totient-function, goldbachs-conjecture

A few weeks ago, I found this question in math.stackexchange:

[Goldbach Conjecture: Subsets of the Euler Totient Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152508/goldbach-conjecture-subsets-of-the-euler-totient-function)

I can not find the relationship between the question asked and Goldbach's conjecture, as the title of the question suggests. Any clue of what the relationship could be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I neither can see how the totient function relates in any way to Goldbach's conjecture.