# Bounding subsets of Euler's totient function

Tags: totient-function, upper-lower-bounds

Let it be some positive integer $n$, and some prime number $q<n$ such that $\gcd\left(q,n\right)=1$

Let it be $S=\left\{ x\,:\,0\leq x\leq n,\,\gcd\left(x,qn\right)=1\right\}$

I conjecture that $\mid S\mid>\lfloor\frac{\varphi\left(qn\right)}{q}\rfloor$, but following the bounding process I developed answering to the question [Goldbach Conjecture: Subsets of the Euler Totient Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2152508/goldbach-conjecture-subsets-of-the-euler-totient-function/3577389#3577389), the most I get for $n$ being some composite number is that $$\mid S\mid>\frac{\varphi\left(qn\right)+\omega\left(n\right)+2}{q}-\omega\left(n\right)$$

Is it the conjecture provable?

As posted in the answer to the question mentioned, it is easily provable for $n$ being some prime number, but not for $n$ being some composite number.

The conjecture follows applying the property that $\gcd\left(k,n\right)=\gcd\left(k+n,n\right)$, as this means that all numbers $k<qn$ such that $\gcd\left(k,qn\right)=1$ are somehow evenly distributed in the intervals $[1,n),[n+1,2n),...,[(q-1)n+1,qn)$. As there are $q$ intervals, one should expect to have approximately $\frac{\varphi\left(qn\right)}{q}$ elements of $S$ in each interval.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: When $n=65$ and $q=7$, $|S| = 40$ and your lower bound $\lfloor \frac{\phi(455)}{7}\rfloor$ is $41$. That appears to be as bad as it gets for small cases, though.

Comment: Thanks @MishaLavrov for the counterexample! Then, do you think that the bound I propose is the best possible? Maybe for a bigger number of distinct prime factors it could be improved, I don't know...